# WPF: long hold over ListViewItem

Tags: wpf, command, listviewitem

I want to catch long hold over `ListViewItem` after the user hold and press left `button` and then release after half second.

This is what i have try so far, i manage to catch the first `click`:

```
<ListView>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown">
        <i:InvokeCommandAction 
                Command="{Binding ListViewItemHoldCommand}"
                 CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=ListViewFiles, Path=SelectedItem}"/>
    </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</ListView>
```

And inside my `ListViewItemHoldCommand` class i catch this click inside this `function`:

```
public void Execute(object parameter)
{

}
```

What next i need to do ?

**EDIT**

I also try this:

```
<Window
x:Name="mainView"
</Window

<i:EventTrigger EventName="PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown">
      <i:InvokeCommandAction 
            Command="{Binding DataContext.ListViewItemHoldCommand, ElementName=mainView}"
            CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListView}}}"/>
</i:EventTrigger>

public void Execute(object parameter)
{
    ListView listView = parameter as ListView;
    if (listView != null)
    {
        var selectedIndex = listView.SelectedIndex;
        var selectedItem = listView.SelectedItem;
    }
}
```

But `selectedIndex` is always `-1` and `selectedItem` always null

Answer (score 0):

They're null because preview is before anything happens. Meaning your code is running before the listviewItem is selected.

To ensure something is selected the usual mvvm approach is to bind selecteditem and act in the setter of the bound property.

Like this:

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/30564.wpf-uneventful-mvvm.aspx#Select_From_List_IndexChanged

Long mouse press has no event.  You have to handle mousedown, introduce a delay and then check if the mouse button is still down.

eg

```
    private async void ListViewItem_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        ListViewItem lvi = sender as ListViewItem;
        await Task.Delay(500);
        if (Mouse.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Do something here");
        }
    }
```

If you're going to re-use the code through your project then refactor into a behaviour.